# How can I aggregate a raster in R using a quantile function?

Tags: raster, r

I'm trying to create a new, smaller NDVI raster with the *upper quantile* of raster values for the new aggregated cells.

```
library(raster)
rast <- raster("ndvi.tif")
```

Now I'd like to create the new raster downsampled by a factor of 10, using a quantile function for the top 25% of the data:

```
rast2 <- aggregate(x = rast, fact = 10, 
    fun = function(i) quantile(i, probs = 0.75, na.rm = T))
```

This always gives an error:

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
Called from: FUN(newX[, i], ...)
```

If I use `mean` or `max` it works just fine, only `quantile` gives an error. I've also tried defining a custom function but with the same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`aggregate` is passing an `na.rm` function to your `fun` function:

```
rast2 <- aggregate(x = rast, fact = 10, 
    fun = function(i) quantile(i, probs = 0.75, na.rm = T))
```

But `fun` is only `function(i)` so it fails. You can fix this either by:

```
   fun = function(i,...) quantile(i, probs=0.75, na.rm=T))
```

to ignore any `na.rm` values, or possibly:

```
   fun = function(i, na.rm) quantile(i, probs=0.75, na.rm=na.rm))
```

which will pass through any `na.rm` value passed to `aggregate`.

This is documented in the help for `raster::aggregate`:

```
  The function ‘fun’ should take multiple numbers, and return a
     single number. For example ‘mean’, ‘modal’, ‘min’ or ‘max’.  It
     should also accept a ‘na.rm’ argument (or ignore it as one of the
     'dots' arguments).
```

Comment: Excellent - I'd read the help and then tried various combinations with/without `na.rm` - and now I've learned how those darned dots work, thank you!